# How to correctly handle this on iPhone X

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, autolayout, iphone-x

My app uses a navigation controller. On this particular screen the navigation bar is transparent, to take advantage of images. The image view is set via the story board. The constraints are:

1. Height 300
2. Top space to Top Layout Guide -64 (To make the image appear behind the navigation bar)
3. Equal width to container

This renders correctly on all devices up to iPhone 8 plus however on the iPhone X it does not. Another issue is; A view I create programatically using X and Y coordinates also shows in the wrong position on iPhone X. Again this works on all devices up to 8 Plus. Below is how I'm create the "card" view:

let card = UIView(frame: CGRect(x:10, y:245, width: viewSize-20, height:80))

Please can you advise how to handle both of these issues on iPhone X without affecting other devices?

Screenshot of issue(s):
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm no expert, but I would leave the area beside the notch for the usual UI stuff: battery, time, etc.

Comment: You make a good point, for this particular screen I chose to hide the status bar (which includes battery, time etc..) to take advantage of the image, however I suspect this all ties in to the new safe area layout introduced with iPhone X. My knowledge on this isn't great though.

Comment: Why aren't you using constraints on the view that you're using x and y points on? And why don't you simply anchor the subviews in this view controller to the top of the view and not the safe area? Both problems solved.

Comment: I probably can switch to constraints for the card view, in theory that should solve that issue. However in terms of the image view, I only have the option to anchor it to the top layout guide (because of navigation controller) and not the very top of the view. Note this is via the storyboard, if I can bypass this programatically please let me know.